# Going from finite to countably infinite.

Tags: real-analysis

This may be silly but I need to be set straight.

I've spent the last 20 pages of the book learning why if it works for finite things it doesn't **necessarily** work for countably infinite, of course if something works for countably infinite it works for finite amount.

Anyway I know $\sum^n_{i=1}a_i\le b$ say for all n. How can I jump to $\sum^\infty_{i=1}a_i\le b$?

I want to say limits. if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\sum^n_{i=1}a_i)\le b$ then

$\forall\epsilon>0\exists N\in\mathbb{N}:n>N\implies \sum^n_{i=1}a_i-b<\epsilon$

Which is trivially seen to be true.

Is it because that $b$ is not a function of $n$ this works, b works for all n being the critical thing that means this works for countably infinite, rather than just finite?

(I think so, but without a book holding my hand I get scared!)

Comment: Yes, the fact that b is independent of n is essential.

Comment: @mathematician That's not true. If $s_n\leqslant t_n$ for all but finitely many $n$, then $\lim s_n\leqslant \lim t_n$ (provided the limits exist). In this case $t_n=b$ for every $n$ and $s_n=\sum^na_i$.

Comment: If $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i$ exists, then your statement is true. It might be easier to prove the contrapositive. Take $t=\sum\limits_{1}^{\infty} a_i$. If $t>b$, then take $\varepsilon = ({t-b})/{2}$ and arrive at a contradiction.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff what? In this case s_n <= b FOR ALL n

Comment: Minor nitpick.  You know $a$ is true and you want to prove $b$.  So you show $b \implies a$ so $b$ being true is consistent.  Which doesn't actually prove $b$ is true.  Just that b *might* be true.  Prove if $a_n \le b$ for all $n$ and $\lim a_n = c$ then $c \le b$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to go to the definitions.

If $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \le b$ for all $i$, then sequence $\{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i| n \in \mathbb N\}$ is bounded above by $b$. So as the reals have the least upper bound property $\beta= \sup \{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i| n \in \mathbb N\}\le b$ exists.

We actually have a problem in that we don't actually know that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n a_i$ exists.  It's possible $a_i =(-1)^i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i = \{-1|0\} \le 0$ but $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i$ does not exist.

However if we know that $\sum a_i$ is *increasing* we are okay. (For instance if $a_i \ge 0$).

We know that if $\{c_n\}$ is a sequence and $c_i \le c_{i+1}$ and $c_i \le b$ then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} c_i = \beta = \sup \{c_i\}$.

That follows by definition.  For any $\epsilon > 0$ then $\beta - \epsilon < \beta$ is no an upper bound (as $\beta$ is least upper bound.)  So there is an $M$ so that $\beta - \epsilon < c_M \le \beta$.  So for all $n \ge M$, $c_n \ge c_M > \beta - \epsilon$.  So by definition  $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} c_i = \beta = \sup \{c_i\}$

And we are done:

The sequence $\{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i| n \in \mathbb N\}$ and is bounded above so $\beta =\sup \{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i| n \in \mathbb N\}$ exists and as the sequence is increasing $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i := $(by definition) $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i = \beta= \sup \{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i| n \in \mathbb N\}\le b$.

Answer (score 0):

One way to describe this example is to say that the set $B=(-\infty,b]=\{c\in \mathbb R: c\leq b\}$ is a closed set, or to say it is a sequentially closed set: If $(c_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is a sequence of members of $B$ that converges to c, then $c\in B.$

So if $c_n=\sum_{i=1}^na_i\in B$ for each $n,$ and if $c=\lim_{n\to \infty}c_n$ exists, then $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i=\lim_{n\to \infty}c_n=c\in B.$

One thing that doesn't work at infinity is that if $c_n<b$ for all $n$, and if $c=\lim_{n\to \infty}c_n$ exists, we cannot conclude that $c<b,$ but only that $c\leq b.$ For example let $b=1$ and $c_n=1-2^{-n}.$ Then $c=\lim_{n\to \infty} c_n=1=b.$